# how can i use active pseudo class to show something

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

im trying to show a text "copied" after an image has been clicked, with :active class but testing with hover and i cant figure it out. Like a :hover on a navbar to see a drop down menu

```css
.copy {
  display: flex;

  &__text {
    display: none;
  }

  &__img {
    max-width: 1.2rem;
    height: 1.2rem;
    margin-left: 0.3rem;
    cursor: pointer;

    &:active {
      filter: opacity(0.5) drop-shadow(0 0 0 rgb(133, 177, 0));
    }
  }
}
.copy__img:active .copy__text {
  display: block;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
    <div className="copy">
      <img
        className="copy__img"
        src={CopyIcon}
        onClick={copyText}
        alt="copy icon"
      />
      <p className={"copy__text"}>copied</p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The :active pseudo-class is used to select and style the active link or any other element. It is activated by user.

**An element becomes active when the user `clicks` on the link or the element and presses down the mouse button.**

[More details on documentation](https://www.w3docs.com/learn-css/active.html)

> :active pseudo-class work with user click not with hovering the element.

If you are working with React.js, you can use this methods :-

jsx:

```
    import "./App.scss";
    import { useState } from "react";

    export default function App() {
       const [mouse, setMouse] = useState(false);

       return (
         <div className="App">
          {/* :active && mouseEventListner*/}
          <h4>:active && mouseEventListner</h4>
          <div className="div">
             <img
                className="div__img"
                src="https://picsum.photos/200/200"
                alt="random"
                onMouseDown={() => setMouse(true)}
                onMouseUp={() => setMouse(false)}
             />
             {mouse && <p className="div__text">copied</p>}
          </div>

          {/* :active && :hover */}
          <h4>:active && :hover</h4>
          <div className="parentDiv">
             <img
                className="parentDiv__childDiv1"
                src="https://picsum.photos/200/200"
                alt="random"
             />
             <div className="parentDiv__childDiv2">copied</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

scss:

```
    .div{
        display: flex;
        &__img{
           width: 5rem;
           cursor: pointer;
           &:active{
              filter: opacity(0.5) drop-shadow(0 0 0 rgb(133, 177, 0));
          }
       }
       &__text{
          background-color: red;
       }
    }


    .parentDiv{
        width: 6rem;
        background-color: teal;
        cursor: pointer;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        padding: 1rem;
        &:hover > &__childDiv2 {
           display: block;
        }
        &__childDiv1, &__childDiv2{
           width: 6rem;
           height: 6rem;
        }
        &__childDiv1{
           background-color: white;
           &:active{
              filter: opacity(0.5) drop-shadow(0 0 0 rgb(133, 177, 0));
           }
        }
        &__childDiv2{   
           display: none;
           background-color: red;
        }
    }
```

:active pseudo class only works when clicking.

Comment: I am trying to have a text show, when an image has been clicked

Comment: did you tried testing this with clicking the element instead of testing with hovering?

Comment: ive reworded the question, hopefully its more clear